# Error in plotting quiver ufunc 'isfinite'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following lists, and I want to plot using the plt.quiver but I got the following error.
I do not know what to modify the list so the plot is plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[0.5, 0.09113826200606436, 0.09090926587458355, 0.09090909053329622, 0.09090909090689524, 0.09090909090901886]
y=[-0.5, -0.09113826200606436, -0.09090926587458355, -0.09090909053329618, -0.09090909090689503, -0.09090909090901889]
u=[0.9, 0.0005041764133415783, 3.84924083801641e-07, -8.267483364576833e-10, -4.830719158022134e-12, -1.584843367652411e-13]
v=[-0.9, -0.0005041764133415783, -3.84924083801641e-07, 8.267483364576833e-10, 4.830691402446519e-12, 1.584843367652411e-13]
colour=['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']

plt.quiver(x,y,u,v, colour)


TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2e445afc7e85> in <module>
    138 print(colour)
    139 plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,30)
--> 140 plt.quiver(x,y,u,v, colour)
    141 plt.scatter(stable_point_xaxis, stable_point_yaxis, color='blue')
    142 #plt.scatter(uNew, vNew, color='red')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2367         cls = type(a)
   2368     else:
-> 2369         condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2370         cls = MaskedArray
   2371     result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: If you have a Gigantic Figure, say the size of the Solar System, so that an arrow with size 0.9 units is represented as 150E6 km long (that is, 1 AU), then the smallest arrow that you desire to represent in the same Figure would be long 26 mm (no! I was joking...! the smallest arrow would be 26.4 mm).

Answer (score 0):

If you plot each arrow individually, Matplotlib does her job, but all the arrows look the same, even if they are not of the same size (in your data, they are apart by **13 orders of magnitude**).

My **guess** is that Matplotib encounters an error when she tries to rasterize, *in the same scale*, arrow objects that are so different in terms of their dimensions.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import quiver, show

x = [0.5, 0.09113826200606436, 0.09090926587458355, 0.09090909053329622, 0.09090909090689524, 0.09090909090901886]
y = [-0.5, -0.09113826200606436, -0.09090926587458355, -0.09090909053329618, -0.09090909090689503, -0.09090909090901889]
u = [0.9, 0.0005041764133415783, 3.84924083801641e-07, -8.267483364576833e-10, -4.830719158022134e-12, -1.584843367652411e-13]
v = [-0.9, -0.0005041764133415783, -3.84924083801641e-07, 8.267483364576833e-10, 4.830691402446519e-12, 1.584843367652411e-13]
color = 'r r r r r'.split()

for x_, y_, u_, v_ in zip(x,y,u,v):
    quiver(x_, y_, u_, v_, color=color)
show()
```

[image]